# processing numpy matrices in python functions

Tags: python-2.7

I have a some problem with part of my python code. I am simply defining a function which works on an input matrix and creates a new matrix which has row shifted values in it. The code goes like this:

```
import numpy
import math

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore', over='ignore')

H = numpy.array(range(40000),dtype =float).reshape((200,200)) 

for i in range(0,200):
    for j in range(0,200):
        if (i<50):
            H[i][j] = 50
        else:
            H[i][j] = 0

def X_im1_j (X):
    d = numpy.array(range(40000),dtype =float).reshape((200,200))
    for i in range(0,200):
        for j in range(0,200):
            if (i<1):
                d[i][j] = X[i][j]
            else:
                d[i][j] = X[i-1][j]
    return d

H_im1_j = numpy.zeros(shape=(200,200))

for r in range(0,200):
    H_im1_j = X_im1_j (H)
    print(H_im1_j)
```

Here I am creating an H matrix first then assigning values to upper 50 rows through a loop. Then I am defining a function for creating row shifted matrix. Then I created the `matrix H_im1_j (H[i-1][j])…`then in the loop I am updating this `matrix H_im1_j` using the `function X_im1_j()`. As the loop progress the resultant matrix should fill up eventually….But I am getting `H_im1_j as H` only after every iteration. Is there any scoping rule which restricting the process? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which is working for me, just changed np.seterr to numpy.seterr

```
import numpy
import math

numpy.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore', over='ignore')

H = numpy.array(range(40000),dtype =float).reshape((200,200))
for i in range(0,200):
    for j in range(0,200):
        if (i<50):
            H[i][j] = 50
        else:
            H[i][j] = 0

def X_im1_j (X):
    d = numpy.array(range(40000),dtype =float).reshape((200,200))
    for i in range(0,200):
        if (i<1):
            d[i][j] = X[i][j]
        else:
            d[i][j] = X[i-1][j]
    return d

H_im1_j = numpy.zeros(shape=(200,200))

for r in range(0,200):
    H_im1_j = X_im1_j (H)
    print(H_im1_j)
```